# Trouble with formatting awk script - changing file format

Tags: awk

I'm writing an awk script that when I want it to run I have to use the command prompt

awk -f file.awk fileitreadsfrom

I am editing the "fileitreadsfrom" in my awk script. 
I am having trouble editing though in my script. So for example, I want

> 1209480997,0997-464,Anthony,Alvarado,3,Standard,Ira A Fulton
>   Engineering - Information Technology,Senior,aalvar33,Non-Resident,

to read as

> Alvardo:Anthony:1209480997:Ira A Fulton Engineering - Information
>   Technology:Senior:aalvar33:aalvar@email.com

What I've tried so far

```
#!/bin/awk -f 

awk '/Alvardo/ {print $4}' fileitreadsfrom
```

I've also tried substr but I'm afraid I'm not getting it right

How can I edit the line and rearrange it to the apporiate format?

Comment: Are you trying to use `fileitreadsfrom` inside the awk script? I've mentioned in the other answer that you shouldn't do that.

Comment: Why do you use the `awk` keyword inside the awk script? How would you expect that to be interpreted

Comment: My mistake, I'm still new and learning

Comment: How do you come up with email addresses if it's not in the input file?  Before you convert it to a script file it's faster to try it on the command line for simple scripts.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I want to make sure I understand. You say you are editing the input file, but that is not really how awk is normally used. It is more standard to take an input file and write to a different output file (or write to the terminal, stdout).

Second, if all you are doing is re-ordering the fields and changing the delimiters from commas to colons, it should be straightforward.

```
awk -F, '{printf "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", 
          $4, $3, $1, $7, $8, $9, "email"}'
```

But if the email is calculated as first initial last name, then you can try this:

```
awk -F, '{email = sprintf ("%s%s@email.com", substr ($3, 1, 1), substr ($4, 1, 5); 
          printf "%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", 
          $4, $3, $1, $7, $8, $9, email}'
```

You can do it more efficiently, but I used sprintf and printf to make clear what I was doing. If characters matter, make it shorter. But I hope it is easier to understand this way.